# <p-fileUpload> Change icon on PrimeNG on file upload

Tags: angular, primeng

Is it possible to change the icon on choose button on [file upload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload) ?
In my case it is always "+".

```html
<p-fileUpload 
  class="btn-primary"
  auto="true"
  mode="basic"
  name="demo[]" 
  chooseLabel="Upload"
  [url]="apiImageLocation" 
  accept="image/*"
  maxFileSize="2000000" 
  (onUpload)="onUploadImageSuccess($event)" 
  (onError)="onUploadImageError($event)">
</p-fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override font awesome *plus* icon in the CSS of your component :

```css
::ng-deep .ui-fileupload-choose .fa-plus::before {
  content: "\F0A6";
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zn5bty)

Comment: Ok, so restrict it to *ui-fileupload-choose* class (I edited my message and Stackblitz)

Answer (score 1):

You can now set the icons with attributes:

```
<p-fileUpload chooseIcon="pi pi-upload" uploadIcon="pi pi-arrow-up" cancelIcon="pi pi-stop></p-fileUpload>
```

No longer any need for css overrides for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .ui-fileupload-choose .fa-plus::before {
  content: "\F0A6";
   background: red;
}

::ng-deep .ui-button .fa-upload::before{
  background: red;
   content: "\F0A6";

}

::ng-deep .ui-button .fa-close::before{
  background: red;
   content: "\F0A6";

}


but new primeng pi-upload,pi-times
```